# Iterating through lists of different lengths which are inside a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
a = [[1, [0], [0], [1, [0]]], [1, [0], [0], [1, [0]]], [1, [0], [0]]]
```

and I would like to take all the integers and make a string out of them:

```
b = '1001010010100'
```

Is there any way I can do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the more general question here is how to iterate over n-dimensional lists. Very good question...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a rebellious approach:

```
a = [[1, [0], [0], [1, [0]]], [1, [0], [0], [1, [0]]], [1, [0], [0]]]
b = ''.join(c for c in str(a) if c.isdigit())
```

Comment: This was pretty smart.

Comment: ...and a +1 for ingenuity... I wouldn't really recommend this approach though...

Comment: @JaredGoguen why though?

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 it's a very clever but brittle solution because it solves only this particular case. what if we only want to return digits that are n-levels deep? iterating through `a` is more "pythonic" because it maintains the structure of `a` while the operation `str(a)` destroys the structure of `a`. still I felt compelled to give `+1` for this solution :P

Answer (score 5):

You can write a function that recursively iterates through your nested listed and tries to convert each element to an iterator.

```
def recurse_iter(it):
    if isinstance(it, basestring):
        yield it
    else:
        try:
            for element in iter(it):
                for subelement in recurse_iter(element):
                    yield subelement
        except TypeError:
            yield it
```

This hideous function will produce a list of the strings and non-iterable members in an object.

```
a = [[1, [0], [0], [1, [0]]], [1, [0], [0], [1, [0]]], [1, [0], [0]]]
list(recurse_iter(a))
# [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Converting this to a string is straight forward enough.

```
''.join(map(str, recurse_iter(a)))
```

Comment: While it works for this case, a general solutions should probably check if an element is a string so that it doesn't start yielding individual characters.

Comment: @BrianSchlenker That case will cause an infinite recursion. I'll update in a second.

Comment: I like this answer since it gives you the option to [conditionally] modify all items in the list, no matter how deep they are.

Answer (score 1):

Code -

```
def solve(x):                                                        
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return str(x)
    return ''.join(solve(y) for y in x)

print(solve(a))
```

Output -

```
1001010010100
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [flatten](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Python) function:

```
def flatten_str(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return "".join(flatten_str(a) for a in x)
    else:
        return str(x)
```